# Does WPF refresh drawing similar to Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

So if I have a WPF window, would moving another window over the WPF window cause the WPF window to do thousands of redraws like Windows Forms?

I am wondering the effects of using vectors in this case, as opposed to everything being bitmap-based like Window Forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a peek at the [WPF architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441.aspx) to get an idea of how it's set up.

To answer your specific question:  WPF uses a retained mode drawing system.  In particular, that means that any redrawing necessary (which may be necessary) is handled behind the scenes without your intervention.

By contrast, GDI uses immediate mode; i.e. you essentially write pixels directly and if -for any reason- those pixels need refreshing, you need to re-render.

WPF doesn't *necessarily* actually cache everything - that depends on the OS and memory availability amongst other things.  However, if it does need to re-render, it'll use the scene graph you last provided to do so; it's transparent to the programmer.  Also, even though it "uses" DirectX, that basically just means it's doing a best-effort case to use hardware support insofar available and implemented for that feature.  Not all graphics cards nor all WPF features are fully accelerated.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149763/how-do-you-determine-if-wpf-is-using-hardware-or-software-rendering) concerns telling the different rending modes apart and the consequence that entails.

Answer (score 1):

WPF's rendering is handled completely differently than Windows Forms.  It's using DirectX to render itself, so the rendering tends to have quite a bit less problems of this nature than Windows Forms.

(This does, however, cause some of its own issues - in particular, it has a higher requirement for the graphics card to get decent performance...)