# Detect if IE11 is using software rendering?

Tags: webgl

I'm running a webgl app on two different PCs, both with capable graphics cards that run fine in FF, Chrome and Opera. On my laptop (with an Nvidia card) IE also runs fine. On the desktop PC (which has an ATI card), IE seems to switch to software rendering - a console message indicates this. On this computer, the rendering is unusably slow so I'd like to switch to using the settings I use for mobile devices, which would perform ok.

So my question is, is there any way to know if IE is using software rendering?

Comment: Possibly [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/149763/2596334).

Comment: Thanks but I doubt I can use Windows Presentation Foundation functions in WebGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [August 2014 update for IE11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/08/13/august-updates-for-internet-explorer.aspx) included support for [failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.2.1) at context creation, which should fail to create the context if it's using software rendering.