# wpfgfx_0400 makes app hang

Tags: wpf, windows, freeze

I'm developing WPF textual testing application.
Everything is OK, but sometimes my app stops responding.

Using Process Explorer I've found out that there's a problem in wpfgfx_0400.dll. Moreover, in most of cases entire OS could stop responding after a while. I think it could be video layer (driver?) issue, because music continue playing.

All windows/.net/video driver updates are installed. Windows7x64, .NET4.0, Radeon HD7700

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, such errors are almost always a driver issue. You can try to verify that this is hardware/driver related problem by forcing wpf to software render mode - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149763/how-do-you-determine-if-wpf-is-using-hardware-or-software-rendering) for more info on how to do it. If you don't have any problems in software mode then it's a driver issue, so you can try some older driver versions and see if it goes away.