# WTSIsRemoteSession always returns TRUE

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I'm currently writing a Windows service, which also does something when a user logs on. There was the idea to do nothing if the logon comes from a remote computer (e.g. Remote desktop), and tried to find a way to dermine this. But following does not work - it **always** returns true (Windows 10 64 bit V1809) - is there something I doing wrong here?

```
DWORD SvcHandlerEx(DWORD controlCode, DWORD eventType, ... )
{
    ...

    switch(controlCode)
    {
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE:
        {
            WTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION *pSessInfo = (WTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION *)pEvtData;
            // invoke SessionChangeHandler(eventId, pSessInfo->dwSessionId)
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}

...

VOID SessionChangeHandler(DWORD reason, DWORD sessionId)
{
    LPWSTR *pSessionInfo = nullptr;
    DWORD dataLen = 0;
    BOOL isRDP = false;

    if (!WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, 
                                     WTSIsRemoteSession, &pSessionInfo, &dataLen))
    {
        // Do some error handling...
        return;
    }

    if (dataLen)
    {
        if (dataLen)
        {
            isRDP = (bool)pSessionInfo;    // Always 1 (TRUE) !!!
        }

        WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: I also tried with WTSClientProtocolType as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001915/how-to-determine-whether-c-sharp-app-running-under-citrix - but in this case I do not get "2" (RDP protocol) when connecting from a remote computer...strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-_wts_info_class) for `WTSIsRemoteSession`:

> WTSIsRemoteSession
>
> Determines whether the current session is a remote session.
>
> **The `WTSQuerySessionInformation` function returns a value of `TRUE` to indicate that the current session is a remote session, and `FALSE` to indicate that the current session is a local session**. This value can only be used for the local machine, so the `hServer` parameter of the `WTSQuerySessionInformation` function must contain `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE`.
>
> Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista:  This value is not supported.

This implies that the *return value* of `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` holds the value you are looking for, and whatever memory the function may allocate, if any, is secondary and should be ignored when querying `WTSIsRemoteSession`, eg:

```cpp
VOID SessionChangeHandler(DWORD reason, DWORD sessionId)
{
    LPWSTR *pSessionInfo = nullptr;
    DWORD dataLen = 0;

    bool isRDP = WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSIsRemoteSession, &pSessionInfo, &dataLen);
    if ((!isRDP) && (GetLastError() != 0))
    {
        // Do some error handling...
        return;
    }

    if (pSessionInfo)
        WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

    // use isRDP as needed...
    ...
}
```

However, if you find that `isRDP` is always true in this case, then the documentation is misleading and you should check the *contents* of the `pSessionInfo` buffer instead. You are setting your `isRDP` variable based on whether `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` allocates any memory at all, you are not looking at what is actually inside the data.

For instance, assuming `dataLen` is being set to `sizeof(BOOL)` on output then cast your `pSessionInfo` pointer to a `BOOL*` pointer and dereference it, eg:

```cpp
VOID SessionChangeHandler(DWORD reason, DWORD sessionId)
{
    LPWSTR *pSessionInfo = nullptr;
    DWORD dataLen = 0;

    if (!WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSIsRemoteSession, &pSessionInfo, &dataLen))
    {
        // Do some error handling...
        return;
    }

    bool isRDP = * (BOOL*) pSessionInfo;
    WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

    // use isRDP as needed...
    ...
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
VOID SessionChangeHandler(DWORD reason, DWORD sessionId)
{
    BOOL *isRDP = nullptr;
    DWORD dataLen = 0;

    if (!WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSIsRemoteSession, (LPWSTR*)&isRDP, &dataLen))
    {
        // Do some error handling...
        return;
    }

    // use *isRDP as needed...

    WTSFreeMemory(isRDP);
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

On the other hand, if `dataLen` is instead being set to `sizeof(UCHAR)` on output then cast your `pSessionInfo` pointer to a `UCHAR*` pointer and dereference it, eg:

```cpp
VOID SessionChangeHandler(DWORD reason, DWORD sessionId)
{
    LPWSTR *pSessionInfo = nullptr;
    DWORD dataLen = 0;

    if (!WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSIsRemoteSession, &pSessionInfo, &dataLen))
    {
        // Do some error handling...
        return;
    }

    bool isRDP = * (UCHAR*) pSessionInfo;
    WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

    // use isRDP as needed...
    ...
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
VOID SessionChangeHandler(DWORD reason, DWORD sessionId)
{
    UCHAR *isRDP = nullptr;
    DWORD dataLen = 0;

    if (!WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSIsRemoteSession, (LPWSTR*)&isRDP, &dataLen))
    {
        // Do some error handling...
        return;
    }

    // use *isRDP as needed...

    WTSFreeMemory(isRDP);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood the documentation (or worded badly - "The return value of WTSQuerySessionInformationW returns ..." might be more clear). 
However, I tried as you suggested: GetLastError() returns 0 (was called immediately after WTSQuerySessionInformationW), but "isRdp" is always "TRUE".
To be sure, I rebooted and checked this without connecting via remote desktop - "isRdp" is "TRUE". I also tried to catch errors via "if (GetLastError() != 0)" - nothing changes. Are there other ways to find out if a remote desktop connection was established?

Comment: Have much thanks - you helped me a lot. I got it: My usage of WTSQuerySessionInformationW() is correct, but I did not derefernce the data properly (I did "isRdp = (bool)pSessionInfo" instead of "isRdp =*(bool *)pSessionInfo"). A little mistake - big impact....

Comment: @WillyK. Note that Microsoft does not use `bool` (lowercase) in its APIs, it (typically) uses `BOOL` (uppercase) instead, for compatibility with C. See [BOOL vs. VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOLEAN vs. bool](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923): "*Newest on the scene is `bool`, which is a C++ data type that has the value `true` or `false`. **You won’t see this used much (if at all) in Win32** because Win32 tries to remain C-compatible.*"

Comment: In my own testing (on Windows 10 Pro 22H2), I find the value of the buffer is correct – if I have a remote RDP session 2, plus the standard 0=Services and 1=Console, then I find the buffer is 0x00 for sessions 0 and 1, but 0x01 for session 2. The statement in the docs that implies you look at the return value not the buffer is just wrong/misleading, so you could improve your answer by deleting your example code which makes that false assumption.

Comment: @SimonKissane What you describe is already covered by the 2nd half of my answer: "*However, if you find that `isRDP` is always true in this case, then the documentation is misleading and you should check the contents of the `pSessionInfo` buffer instead.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Yes, but my point is your answer is worded "If A then B, if not-A then C". Since A is false, the whole "If A then B, if not-A then..." bit is unnecessary and just confusing people.

Comment: @SimonKissane I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, consider your first block of example code – it is just wrong, it doesn't work. That might not be clear from the documentation, but if you try it you will see – whereas your second and third code block is correct. So your answer would be briefer and easier to understand if you deleted that first code block.

Comment: In fact datalLen == 1 so you have to cast pSessionInfo into a UCHAR* or bool* lowercase or it will almost always return true depending of the other bytes :
bool isRDP = * (UCHAR*) pSessionInfo;